# Java Generics Bound Type & Type Arguments

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a generic interface with a bound type and two implementations:

```
public interface IShapeConverter<T extends IShape> {

  String convert(T shape);

}

public class SquareConverter implements IShapeConverter<Square> {

  public String convert(final Square square) {
    ...
  }

}

public class CircleConverter implements IShapeConverter<Circle> {

  public String convert(final Circle circle) {
    ...
  }

}
```

Now I'm wondering what the best way to get an instance would be, based on the IShape type. I was thinking of having a static method in the interface like this:

```
static IShapeConverter getInstance(final IShape shape) {
  if (shape instanceof Circle) {
    return new CircleConverter();
  }
  return new SquareConverter();
}
```

but I don't really want to have to explicitly check the type. This also gives an unchecked warning when I call convert:

```
void someFunction(final IShape shape) {

  final IShapeConverter converter = IShapeConverter.getInstance(shape);

  final String = converter.convert(shape); // Unchecked warning

  ...
}
```

There has to be a better way to do this..

edit: Adding full unchecked warning

Unchecked call to ‘convert(T)’ as a member of raw type ‘my.package.IShapeConverter’

Comment: post the entire Unchecked warning

Comment: That looks like a really bad idea to put it in the interface. Interface itself shouldn't have to know about all the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce some more generic type arguments on your methods, but unfortunately, the best you can do is move the unchecked warning elsewhere:

```java
static <T extends IShape> IShapeConverter<T> getInstance(final T shape) {
    if (shape instanceof Circle) {
        return (IShapeConverter<T>) new CircleConverter(); // Unchecked warning
    }
    return (IShapeConverter<T>) new SquareConverter(); // Unchecked warning
}

<T extends IShape> void someFunction(final T shape) {

    final IShapeConverter<T> converter = IShapeConverter.getInstance(shape);

    final String result = converter.convert(shape);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer using an `enum` to define the type of shape and get instance based on it rather than checking `instanceof` as the type does not change the class can.

I tried this locally, didn't see any checked exceptions

```
void someFunction(final IShape shape) {
    final IShapeConverter converter = IShapeConverter.getInstance(shape.getType());
    final String result = converter.convert(shape);
}

enum ShapeType {

    SQUARE,
    CIRCLE;
}

interface IShape {

    ShapeType getType();
}

class Square implements IShape {

    @Override
    public ShapeType getType() {
        return ShapeType.SQUARE;
    }
}

class Circle implements IShape {

    @Override
    public ShapeType getType() {
        return ShapeType.CIRCLE;
    }
}

interface IShapeConverter<T extends IShape> {

    String convert(T shape);

    static IShapeConverter getInstance(final ShapeType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case CIRCLE:
                return new CircleConverter();
            case SQUARE:
                return new SquareConverter();
            default:
        }
        return null;
    }

}

static class SquareConverter implements IShapeConverter<Square> {

    public String convert(final Square square) {
        return null;
    }
}

static class CircleConverter implements IShapeConverter<Circle> {

    public String convert(final Circle circle) {
        return null;
    }
}
```